# Calling method from another file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a beginner in Objective-C. I would like to call the method `two` in file `you.m` from file `me.m`. Could you please teach me with simple example showing below to understand. Thank you!

**you.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface you : NSObject {
}
- (NSString *)one;
- (NSString *)two;
@end
```

**you.m**

```
#import "you.m"

@implementation you
- (NSString *)one {
    NSString *a = @"this is a test.";
    return a;
}
-(NSString *)two {
    NSString *b = [self one];
    return b;
}
@end
```

**me.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface me : NSObject {
}
@end
```

**me.m**

```
#import "you.h"
#import "me.h"

@implementation me
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    //NSString *obj = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
    //NSString *str = [obj two]; // dont work
    //NSString *str = [self two]; // dont work
    // I'd like to call method *two* from here.
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `me` class, create an instance of `you`.

```
you *objectYou=[you new];
```

As `two` returns a string, you need to store it :

```
NSString *string=[objectYou two];
```

In your code:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    you *objectYou=[you new];
    NSString *str = [objectYou two]; 
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
```

*NOTE:  Follow naming conventions. Class names must start with Capital letter like **Me**, **You**.*

EDIT:

As you are learning, I would like to add one more thing, as you are calling `one` from `two`. If `one` is not meant to be called outside `you` class. You can define it in `.m` and remove the declaration from `.h`.

Answer (score 3):

Simple, create an instance of `You` class in `Me` class and call that member function. Like so -

```
you *youInstance = [[you alloc] init];
NSString *retStr = [youInstance two];
```

Btw, its a good practice to [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) class names.

Also note this -

```
@interface you
 - (NSString *) twoInstanceMethod;
 + (NSString *) twoClassMethod;
@end

NSString *retStr = [you twoClassMethod]; // This is ok

NSString *retStr = [you twoInstanceMethod]; // this doenst't work, you need an instance:

//so we create instance.
you *youInstance = [[you alloc] init];
NSString *retStr = [youInstance two];
```

Hope this clears some concepts...

Comment: what about return string from two?

Comment: that i left it for @Dede to fill in the blanks. But I will edit my answer for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Nice answer  liked it :)

Comment: I got it now. Thank you very much for your help!